# Regex match only first occurrence after key string

Tags: .net, regex

Regex:

```
(?<=KEY.{1,99})([0-9]*)
```

Example text:

```
test 74488 hdhd2 768 788 KEY bla gjjjcrs 6448. gfudj778. 2 bla 77545 77890 7754
```

Desired result:

```
6448
```

I need only first match of digits group after KEY. Can I make regexp stop searching after first digit group occurrence to reduce CPU load? Or I don't need it?

Comment: if you want it to stop searching just use `if` condition..don't find all matches..you can also try `.*?\bKEY\b.*?\b(\d+)\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `(.*) (KEY) ([^0-9]*)(\d+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vP7sW6/1)

If you want to match only those digits after KEY: `(?:.* KEY) (?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)`

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not what I wanted. Added desired result to my question.

Comment: (?:.* KEY) (?:[^0-9]*)(\d+). Thank you, works fine for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this one :

```
KEY.*?(\d+)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vP7sW6/3).

Comment: Thanks for that demo, pretty usefull site.

Comment: @Fastbrainx if you want to look for the explanation, you can just find it in the link provided.

Comment: @Veeke Glad to hear that.